# Cite completion on Texmaker

Tags: texmaker

I'm working with TexMarker on Win7.

My *.bib file (I'm using biblatex) has about 30 entries, mostly `@Book`and `@Article` but also some `@ELECTRONIC`. Problem is that the `@ELECTRONIC` entries doesn't appear in TexMarkers `\cite` completion list.

What can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File a bug or feature request for Texmaker. If you are a good programmer it might not be hard to add the functionality yourself, though.

Comment: I filed a bug report: http://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=543

Comment: The bug was fixed in version 3.3.3 (see the bug report link).